# SOAP API Implementation using .NET CORE

Tags: soap, c#, .net

We are trying to migrate this `SOAP API` call from `.NET` to `.NET CORE`.

Kindly help on creating `.NET Core` client code/proxy class using this file - https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl

```
SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement()
```

This code throws below exception:

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: TransportSecurityBindingElement.BuildChannelFactoryCore is not supported.